# Installing elementary OS on XPS 15 9550 with Intel SSD in dual boot Windows 10

Tags: system-installation, hardware, microsoft-windows, filesystem

Hi everyone I'm trying to get elementary to run on my new laptop a Dell XPS 15 9550 with a 500GB SSD with Windows 10 already installed.
First it got always stuck in the elementary logo screen but by appending 'nomodeset' into the boot options I can get it to boot to a live version. But the next problem is that it cannot find my 500GB SSD only the USB drive and nothing else.

So after some research I found it might be related to "Intel Rapid Storage" and looking at my BIOS I can see that the SSD is configured as RAID. Which is rather odd since it's only one drive.

So I guess I have to switch that to AHCI ? But then of course windows won't boot anymore. Will the installation of the grub launcher actually take care of this somehow or is the only way to go to clean up the SSD and reinstall both OS? Will this result in performance loss for Windows 10? What's the deal with the Raid setting?

Answer (score 1):

I looked up your laptop from the Dell website. The HDD is in fact a hybrid drive with a 32 gb ssd inside of the 500 gb mechanical drive. This is the reason that you need the Intel RST driver to work. There is a fix for Ubuntu, and as eOS is a derivative of Ubuntu, it should work. [Ubuntu fix for Intel RST](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2146741)